# Linear Algebra - Prove linear dependent

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A = \{v_1,v_2,....,v_n\}$ $A$ vector group in linear space $V$.

If $v_1 \in Sp\{v_2,....,v_n\}$ and $v_1+v_n \in Sp\{v_1,...v_{n-1}\}$

Prove that $\{v_2,..,v_n\}$ linear dependant.

**My solution (Not full)**

Data:
$$v_1=\lambda_1v_2+...+\lambda_nv_n (*)$$

Not full solution :
$$v_1+v_n=\alpha_1v_1+...+\alpha_{n-1}v_{n-1}$$
$$v_1=\alpha_1v_1+...+\alpha_{n-1}v_{n-1}-v_n$$ 
$$v_1-\alpha_1v_1=\alpha_2v_2+...+\alpha_{n-1}v_{n-1}-v_n$$
$$v_1(1-\alpha_1)=\alpha_2v_2+...+\alpha_{n-1}v_{n-1}-v_n$$

This is the best I could come up with, since $-v_n \neq Sp(-v_n)$ even if $\alpha_1 \neq 1$ I could not conclude anything using $(*)$ Any ideas?

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Subtract $(\ast)$ from your second sum equal to $v_1$. Then show that at least one of $\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2 - \lambda_2, \dots, \alpha_{n-1} - \lambda_{n-1}, -1 - \lambda_n\}$ is not equal to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $$v_1 = \sum\limits_{k=2}^{n} \alpha_i v_i$$ 
and
$$v_1 + v_n = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} \beta_i v_i$$

Substituting the first equation in the second equation, we get

$$ v_n = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \gamma_i v_i = \gamma_1 v_1 + \sum\limits_{k=2}^{n}\gamma_i v_i$$

Substituting the first equation again in the above equation,

$$\gamma_1 \sum\limits_{k=2}^{n} \alpha_i v_i + \sum\limits_{k=2}^{n-1} \gamma_i v_i + (1-\gamma_n) v_n = 0$$

Therefore the vectors $v_2,\ldots,v_n$ are linearly dependant